# How can I change this script in order to delete directories as well?

Tags: scripts, delete, rm

```
find /folder/*.* -mtime +14 -exec rm {} \;
```

I tried `rm -r` and with `-R` argument, but without any result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find /folder/*.* -mtime +14 -exec rm -Rf {} \;
```

```
  
find:  
       search for files in a directory hierarchy

-mtime n: 
       File's  data  was  last  modified  n*24  hours ago. 

-exec command ;
       Execute  command;


-exec command {} +
       This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files

rm:
       remove files or directories

-r, -R, --recursive
       remove directories and their contents recursively

-f, --force
       ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
{}
       Remove (unlink) the FILE(s).
```

This script search for files and remove recursively files/folders that are 14 days along modified

Comment: Did you explain what the command does?

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/directory -type d -ctime +14 -exec rm -rf {} \;

find: unix command for finding file and directories .
/path : state directory path
-type d : only find directories 
-ctime +14 : only consider ones with modification older than 14 days
-exec for such result do the following
rm -rf {} recursively force remove the directory
```

Comment: Did you explain what the command does?